# Include own posts with posts from followed users

Tags: gremlin, gremlinpython

I want to get all posts from the user's followed along with my own posts to create a news feed.

```
g.V().has('name', 'Bob').both('is_friend').out('has_posted').as('posts')
```

The above code only returns posts from followed users.

How do I include my own posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union` and `identity` steps:

```
g.V().has('name', 'Bob').union(
    both('is_friend'),
    identity())
    .out('has_posted').as('posts')
```

You can see a "live" example of your problem [here](https://gremlify.com/1o) (Simply Run your query)